# Debug user activity at a site

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, user-interface, issue-tracking

I have an ecommerce shop deployed on Codeignited an jQuery.Everything work well, however 2-3 users make order via call as they cannot order a product through a shopping cart. They could not explain issue.
Issue can be related with:

```
      1. Front\Server ends code (Mostly users can work well)
      2. User deny cookie
      3. An old browser version or a mobile device
      4. Hosting in-service activity
      5. User misstake(does not fill requred field)
```

I tried to reproduce the error on different PCs and browsers(however only latest versions) and I have not faced the issue.

2nd point I can fix.

How to exclude other points and find the cause? Is Google Analistics can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Is not clear.

2) Display a message that cookies need to be allowed for proper functionality.

3) Depends what is going wrong with the older browser. You could either again display a message saying minimum *this* version is required for the website to function properly or use tools like **[Browsershots](http://browsershots.org/)** to see what needs to be fixed.
To adapt your website to mobile and tablet, you need to implement a **[responsive layout.](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrolldeck.js/decks/responsive/)**

4) If you mean detecting if your website is down, you can use services like **[Cloud Flare](http://www.cloudflare.com/always-online)** that keep your website online even when your server is down by storing cached version of your pages.

5) This is something that can be controlled. You need to validate the data sent by the user, *if* data is in correct format process it, *else* display error(s). There are two types of validations, Client-side (done with JavaScript) and Server-side (done with PHP). Client-side validations can be overriden (hacked) thus Server-side are more secure. You can read all about it **[here.](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Validating-User-Input.html)**